# what is the $E(X^2|X>a)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$ what is the $E(X^2|X>a)$? I am not sure whether it is right. I think the answer is ${1\over \lambda^2}+{1\over\lambda}+a$ as the second moment is ${1\over \lambda^2}+{1\over\lambda}$. Is it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not.  For one thing, your answer doesn't make sense dimensionally.  If we think of $X$ as a time measured in, say, seconds, the rate $\lambda$ is in $1/$seconds, $a$ is in seconds, and $E[X^2 | X > a]$ should be in seconds$^2$.  But $1/\lambda + a$ is in seconds, not seconds$^2$.

By the "lack of memory" property of the exponential distribution, the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X > a$ is the same as the distribution of $a+X$.  Thus you should have 
$E[X^2 | X > a] = E[(a+X)^2]$